# Compress images on client side before uploading using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, image, laravel, compression

I'm following this script for compressing an image : https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress

Does anyone know how to fix this error, for compressing an image before uploading to the server side?
This script is working fine, if i just use php, but with laravel i get this error!

Use of undefined constant image1 - assumed 'image1'

in below the code in view :

```
<div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <h2>Single</h2>
    <input id="inputImage" type="file" accept="image/*" ng-model="image1" image="image1" resize-max-height="800" resize-max-width="800" resize-quality="0.7" resize-type="image/jpg" ng-image-compress/>
    <img ng-src="{{image1.compressed.dataURL}}" />

    <h2>Multiple</h2>
    <input id="inputImage" type="file" accept="image/*" ng-model="imageList" image="imageList" resize-max-height="800" resize-max-width="800" resize-quality="0.7" resize-type="image/jpg" multiple="multiple" ng-image-compress/> 
    <div>
        <img ng-src="{{item.compressed.dataURL}}" ng-repeat="item in imageList" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You should never do such a thing client-side. If you want to save some resources then repeat compression on server-side **only** if the file is still too big.

Comment: why i don't such a thing client-side?

Comment: Client-side Javascript code is vulnerable to malicious changes, and I should never have possibility to skip image compression (that's why you made it)

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek I would not do it myself, but it is possible like with https://github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C . There are no security complications from trying to compress an image client side. The only thing I can think of is that you can't be sure the image is indeed compressed, but you can just put a size limit on the upload on the server.

Comment: @ThomasMoors Protecting the server from eating 5mb images instead of 250KB is under my security label, because the disk space is not something that we have for free (lifetime, performance, etc.)

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek you deny it before upload of course